# Is it possible to create a GAE cron job on a local GAE server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jobs, cron-task

[This](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) link says that GAE does not support cron jobs on the development server. So what are my other options?

I need to send emails out to users when a deadline on their account is reached.

Comment: Why are you using the development server for your actual users?

Comment: Because this is for a class

Answer (score 1):

Use a local cron service, and whrite a script which uses curl or wget to call your cron handler.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use enqueued tasks.

At start-up, your web app could query all users and enqueue a task for each one if there is a deadline, with the task's ETA set to that deadline.

When a task fires, it checks to see if the deadline is "now" or earlier. If so, then execute your deadline processing code. In all cases, examine (the next?) deadline for that user. If one exists then enqueue another task....

Of course, your dev web app server must be running continuously for the enqueued tasks to fire; they are all lost on shut-down.

Any help?